# How to derive Calibrated supply & demand function?

Tags: energy-economics, calibration

Does anybody ever heared of this calibrated form? And how can I derive them?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi! Do you know what "elasticity" means here? (Trying to understand where you have problems.)

Comment: Yes I know about elasticity. Just dont know how to to the algebra do you have any literature where I can find that?